# How pass core data value from tableview to another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to pass data from one table view to another view. Both is the same core data. I just need to make another view to show the correct data according the selected table. Here is the code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetailTwo"]) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:YES];
        DetailViewController *moviewDetailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSManagedObject *movies=[self.moviesArray objectAtIndex:path.row];
        //        NSLog(@"%@", movies);
        Movies *movieL =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[movies valueForKey:@"posterImage"]];
        [moviewDetailVC.movieSelected setPosterImage: movieL];

    }
}
```

But when I go to next screen the data is null

```
2016-08-11 23:12:02.020 OMBDSearch[20175:1682899] (null)
```

I'm new at core data so I need a little help. I've searched a lot for this and didn't solve my problem.

Comment: We need more details. For example, what's `OMBDSearch`?

Comment: This is the name of the project. But this `null` value show when I print `NSLog(@"%@", self.movieSelected);` that is the Core Data class

Comment: It seems that `moviewDetailVC.movieSelected ` was a dictionary/array. Did you initiate it before it was used?

Comment: `movies`is fine, but when I print `moviesL` it show `null` I didn't initiate it

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to do in a difficult way. This way solve my question:

```
    DetailViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    destination.movieSelected = [self.moviesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```